# need correct syntax for update / replace a table entry when column_id name is 'value'

Tags: mysql, sql, magento-1.8

I need to replace a value in a magento store database table where the name of the column is 'value' - that's what is confusing me!!

```
Table name = catalog_product_entity_varchar
column ID = value
value to replace = container2
value to become = container1
```

what syntax should I use?

Comment: This is very basic stuff.  Since you had to ask, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

althoug this is basic UPDATE.

```
 UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET `value` = 'container1'
 WHERE `value` = 'container2'
```

Comment: thanks - that's what i tried first, and just thought it's because i've only had 3 hours sleep in 3 days... lol but it returns this error

#1054 - Unknown column 'container2' in 'where clause'